# CMSIS GPIO_DeInit function enable followed by disable

Tags: stm32, cmsis

Why is the GPIO enabled and then immediately disabled in the following piece of program code?

```
void GPIO_DeInit(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx)
    {
      /* Check the parameters */
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH(GPIOx));
    
      if (GPIOx == GPIOA)
      {
        RCC_AHB1PeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
        RCC_AHB1PeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, DISABLE);
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two lines reset the GPIOx peripheral. Firstly it sets the reset bit in the register to initialize the reset. Then it has to reset the reset  bit to take the peripheral  back to power reset state.